# Running query cannot connect to vendort's database, even dblink exists

Tags: oracle

I have a simple query, which I run on sqldeveloper on put database, but it select data from different vendor database. We have db_link created. but I run, as in my Pro C program:

```
select some_files from mytable trd, vendordbname.vendortable     
where(condition)
```

and I get an error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist    
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"    
*Cause:           
*Action:    
Error at Line: 25 Column:
```

What kind of solution I have to find, to make it run? Use dblink name? or something else? I will appreciate any possible help

Thanks

Comment: the DB_LINK runs as a specific user. it would appear to me that user doesn't have permissions to the vendordbname.vendortable.  `Select * from all_DB_LINKS;` shows all the links and users provided you have permissions to select from that system view.  This would give you the user the link is operating under which can then be checked for proper permissions.

Comment: but the program is running on QA and production servers fine, even if I run it manually, the only I cannot run it from sqldeveloper. I checked all_db_link, everything existed

Comment: I'm not sure I follow the problem then.  Are you saying that in SQL developer logged in as yourself you can run the query in dev/test/prod environments and it works; but when you run it though the application it fails (just in prod?) Is there a synonym being used pointed to the link that the Pro C app user doesn't  have permissions to?

Comment: No, my explanation is  below. When I run on UNIX dev/qa/prod, everything is OK, only sqldeveloepr has problems. I found it and the solution is below

Answer (score 1):

ok, when it runs  with Pro C, everything sets up on UNIX and sqlplus.
When I run it from sqldeveloper I have to add the vendor host name

```
select some_files from mytable trd, vendordbname.vendortable@vendorhost         
where(condition)
```

Comment: So are you saying your access issues were resolved by connecting from a different operating system? It seems more likely to me that you were connecting as a different Oracle user or to a different instance.